# Flutter: Set edge color of the BottomAppBar()

Tags: flutter

I have a `BottomAppBar()` widget

```
BottomAppBar(
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      color: Colors.orange,
      notchMargin: 5,
      child:Container(),
    );
```

And, I want to set the edge color differently like the answer from this question.

[How do I change Bottom App Bar Items Color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62842462/how-do-i-change-bottom-app-bar-items-color)

I'd tried to set the color of the child `Container()`. However, it draws a straight line without the bump at the `FloatingAppButton()`. Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to like this, please check the below code

[image]

Source code

```
Scaffold(
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          notchMargin: 6,
          elevation: 30,
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {},),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {},),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          titleSpacing: 0,
          title: Text("Test"),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFA7343),
        ),
        body: Container(
        ),
      )
```